# Is it ok to install multiple nginx-ingress controllers in a single Kubernetes namespace?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

In AKS, we have a requirement to install two nginx controllers inside a single Kubernetes namespace. In fact, we need to assign each controller a dedicated IP and DNS address. Does it bring any conflict between controllers? Is there any best practice regarding having multiple nginx controllers in a namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered with the help of the official documentations.

> When running [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/#running-multiple-nginx-ingress-controllers), you have the following
> options with regards to which configuration resources it handles:
>
> - **Cluster-wide Ingress Controller (default)**. The Ingress Controller handles configuration resources created in any namespace of
>   the cluster. As NGINX is a high-performance load balancer capable of
>   serving many applications at the same time, this option is used by
>   default in our installation manifests and Helm chart.
> - **Single-namespace Ingress Controller**. You can configure the Ingress Controller to handle configuration resources only from a
>   particular namespace, which is controlled through the
>   `-watch-namespace` command-line argument. This can be useful if you
>   want to use different NGINX Ingress Controllers for different
>   applications, both in terms of isolation and/or operation.
> - **Ingress Controller for Specific Ingress Class**. This option works in conjunction with either of the options above. You can further
>   customize which configuration resources are handled by the Ingress
>   Controller by configuring the class of the Ingress Controller and
>   using that class in your configuration resources. See the section
>   [Configuring Ingress Class](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/#configuring-ingress-class).

You may deploy [any number of ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#multiple-ingress-controllers) within a cluster. When you create an ingress, you should annotate each ingress with the appropriate `ingress.class` to indicate which ingress controller should be used if more than one exists within your cluster.

The main idea is that the multiple Ingress controllers can co-exist and key off the `ingress.class` annotation.

Comment: @EhsanMirsaeedi Did either of you managed to make it work?

Comment: @EhsanMirsaeedi, Please let us know your approach. Thanks in advance!